# How to get local docker daemon info

Tags: docker

I pointed DOCKER_HOST env variable to another host 192.168.99.102, and now don't know how to list local containers..

```
irom@ubuntu-server:~$ echo $DOCKER_HOST
tcp://192.168.99.102:2376
```

so below showing remote , not local containers

```
irom@ubuntu-server:~$ docker info 
Containers: 3
Images: 20
Server Version: 1.9.1
....
```

Comment: Err, try setting the variable back again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways to get the list of local containers

1. Connect to local docker daemon using unix socket as given below

$ docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock ps

2. Unset the existing environment variable DOCKER_HOST using below command

$ unset DOCKER_HOST

$ docker ps